# React Native Routes Not Displayed With react-native-router-flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new to using react native for app development. In my App.js, I have imported Routes.js, in which I have used react-native-router-flux.Somehow, Routes is not displayed. However, when I remove alignItems:'center', the background color disappears but routes is actually displayed. How do I make it so that the app will have both the routes and the background color?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

import Routes from './src/Routes';
const App = ()=> {

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar
        backgroundColor="#1c313a"
        barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <Routes />
    </View>


  );

};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor:'#455a64',
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
  }
});


export default App;
```

Routes.js:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Router, Stack, Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Login from './pages/Login';
import Signup from './pages/Signup';
const Routes = ()=> {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Stack key="root">
                <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" initial={true}/>
                <Scene key="register" component={Signup} title="Register" />
            </Stack>
        </Router>
    );

};


export default Routes;
```

[With alignItems:'center'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5W8p.png)

[With alignItems:'center' the background color disappears and the text cannot be seen because of the background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7sKR.png)

Comment: I think the problems in not at react-native-router-flux, its on your CSS style, and what your background color you want...  Have you set the same `Backgroundcolor` in your initial scene(Login scene)?

Comment: You could just put different color as each background color, then try some css style change, you should find out the problems.